# I get a error for 'useSelector'(action is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, redux

Please check this sandbox and see the error address. (PostsList.js :L30)

I don't see any wrong in my code. But it says `action is undefined`

[image]

My code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/complete-redux-forked-w447ld

Comment: Do not post errors as images or link to code on a external source. Post the relevant code here (perhaps as a stack snippet) as well as the error.

Comment: @mousetail My code is big also it's a react-redux project so snippet isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `export const selectAllPosts` but accessing them as default imports. Try `import {selectAllPosts, fetchPosts} from "./postsSlice";`

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. But I also have another export `selectPostById`. So the other way is to use the `default export` for all of them? And which of them is a better approach?

Comment: There's no better approach, both are ways to export your modules or constants. Best to read up on it and come to your own conclusions on when to use them